# Slow performance on Rally Rest api request and response

Tags: .net, performance, rest, rally

While using Rally Rest.net api to query the data from Rally, the request/response is quite slow. Note that i ignored the factor of client connection speed.

Tried further investigation by Fiddler, i found each request to Rally server has become a pair round-trips ( 1 request responsed authentication 401, and other request actually responsed data), even though use only one instance of RallyRestApi which has accompanied user account info. You could see the red box in attached Fiddler screenshot below.

Is that a bug of Rally Rest.net api? Should i do anything else to avoid it?

Please help!

[image: Rally REST API request/response debug]

**Edit:**

One more issue i found when upload an attachment file to a defect. To upload attachment file, i created an AttachmentContent object and put the file binary content into Content property. Everything works very well, except the response of this request. Rally responses the CreateResult that included the same file binary content. Imagine that we upload a 4MB attachment file in request, and we will receive the response with 4MB file content inside. That causes doubling time of data tranfering between client and server over Http(s) in upload attachment request.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised that you're receiving slow performance with .NET REST, as it's actually one of Rally's more performant APIs. Its data retrieval is multi-threaded, which helps responsiveness.

One thing to be aware of with Rally Webservices - there is a maximum page size in number of records of 200. Thus, if you make a request against Rally that returns 900 records, the .NET API will actually (behind the scenes) make 5 requests against Rally: four pages of 200 records each, and then a fifth page of 100 records.

I hope this helps in terms of explaining the multiple requests.

Comment: We are looking into this defect to see what we can do to remove the unneeded request.
As a side note are you running your code on a single processor machine? It seems from your fiddler log that you are only processing one request at a time.

Comment: Good eye Charles - and thanks for the update on the API-side.

Comment: Many thanks for your comments Charles, Mark.
I've updated the question with one more issue in uploading attachment request via Rally rest api.

Comment: @CharlesFerentchak: yup, i sent one request at a time.

Comment: We've determined this is a defect and will be releasing a fix for it next week.  Also, with regard to the CreateResult returning the entire file again- currently we don't have a way to specify which fields should be returned (like the fetch parameter for queries).  That's a good idea though!

Comment: New version fixing double request issue here: http://developer.rallydev.com/help/rest-api-net